# Vue CLI quesar plugin q-image not showing image

Tags: vue.js, quasar

I am using quasar as a plugin in my vue. I am having trouble using the `q-image` component. When I use the `<img src="../../statics/infocom.png">` the code and image displayed ok but when i use it on

```
<q-img
    :src="'../../statics/infocom.png'"
    spinner-color="white"
    style="height: 140px; max-width: 150px"
    />
```

the image does not show

Comment: Never used quasar but it seems that if you don't use the auto-import feature, you need to manually declare QImg in quasar.conf.js  
Maybe you missed this step ?  
See : https://quasar.dev/vue-components/img#Installation

Comment: @GuillaumeMeral naa it works fine when I am referencing a static image path. But when It is binded it does not work

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine if and only if your relative path is correct.

Or try:

```
  <q-img
    :src="require('../statics/infocom.png')"
    spinner-color="white"
    style="height: 140px; max-width: 150px"
    />
```